# Change name multiple column GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I come of this question: [Google Earth Engine; rename columns in FeatureCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367149/google-earth-engine-rename-columns-in-featurecollection)

I have a Feature Collection I'm exporting as a CSV. I used a shape of points to get NDVI and other index values of aleatory points.

I want to change the column name for one shorter.

For example:

Actually name of me columns are like this:

```
20171016T110031_20171016T110313_T30SUG_NDVI
```

And I want something like this:

```
20171016_NDVI
```

I've been trying whith the question function and system:index metadata but nothing, in another script to download images I used this in a loop but here dont work:

```
while (i < longitud) {
 imagen = ee.Image(lista.get(i))
 fecha=imagen.get('system:index').getInfo().substr(0,8)
 Map.addLayer(imagen.clip(trigo),parametros_visuales,"NDVI "+fecha,false)
 i=i+1
}
```

```
function NDVI(entrada){
var ndvi = entrada.addBands(entrada.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('NDVI'))
return (ndvi)
}
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
 .filterBounds(points)
 .filterDate('2017-10-10','2018-06-15')
 .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT','less_than',10)
Map.centerObject(points,15);
var coleccion_ndvi = sentinel.map(NDVI)

//var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
// Loading shape file
//var points = ee.FeatureCollection("users/tilok/pts")
//Selecting bands
//var image_collection = S1.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-28')
//.filterBounds(points);

// Transform image collection of VH band into image with n bands
var timeSeries = ee.ImageCollection(coleccion_ndvi.select('NDVI')).toBands()
  // Set masked values as -11000, set sameFootprint as false to override original image footprint (useful for working in areas with several tiles)
  .unmask({value: 0, sameFootprint: false});
  
// Extract data for each point
var sampledReg = ee.Image(timeSeries)
      .sampleRegions({
        // Get the sample from the points FeatureCollection.
        collection: points,
        // Properties from the points collection to pass on to the sampled info
        //properties: ['id'],
        // Set the scale to get Sentinel pixels in the FeatureCollection.
        scale: 30,
        tileScale: 8,
        // Return geometries
        geometries: true,
      });

// Transform coordinates into properties in the table.
var featColExport = sampledReg.map(function (feature) {
  // Get geometry
  var coordinates = feature.geometry()
                          // Transform it to the desired EPSG code. Here WGS 84
                          .transform('epsg:32630')
                          // Get coordinates as a list
                          .coordinates();
  // Get both entries of coordinates and set them as new properties
  var resul = feature.set('lon', coordinates.get(0), 
                     'lat', coordinates.get(1));
  // Remove geometry                   
  return resul.setGeometry(null);
});

var DataRenamed = featColExport.map(function(feat){
  return ee.Feature(null, { 
    properties: feat.get(('system:index').substr(0,8))
  })
})

// Export table as csv
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: DataRenamed,
    description: 'DataRenamed',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Comment: I'm seeing that Vince edited the code but I can't find any difference, if you can comment clarifying please. @Vince

Comment: I always include comments in the edit log (which you can see by clicking on "edited {time duration} ago"). I didn't edit your code, just the proper names, the typo, and the name formatting.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I was excited that there was a solution haha, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how things work here. A solution wouldn't come as an edit to the Question, but as an Answer.